# Label `overflow' multiply defined when compiling tex

Tags: overflow

I'm trying to compile my tex file, but it keeps giving me this error

```
Label `overflow' multiply defined.
```

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Look for `\label{overflow}` in your document.  There are at least two of these, which is not allowed.  Rename the duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your sources. You have repeat `\label{overflow}` in your document. This most probably means you have used the same name more than one time (solution is to delete the redundant ones, or rename repeats to e.g. `overflow-1`,  `overflow-2`, ..., or --much better-- add some description to the label, e.g. `overflow-length`, `overflow-width` or some such).

Another possibility is that you `\include{...}` or `\input{...}` the file containing the offending label several times.

Take a look at your `*.log` file, it should help pinpointing the source lines (yes, it is quite verbose and a pain to navigate).

Comment: Thanks it worked!